# Why does iCal show a question mark person icon even though the only attendee for the event has accepted it?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, calendar.app

I have a simple event in iCal with one attendee. I sent an invitation to the attendee via iCal and they accepted the invitation.

When I double click on the event or do `Get Info`, it shows the attendee with a green check mark next to their name (I assume this indicates the acceptance of the invitation). However, the event in iCal shows an icon of a person with a question mark next to their name. Why? Do I need to do something further to complete the event?

I am running Lion and have iCal 5.0, but the most recent [information about symbols on Apple's site](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=iCal/3.0/en/symbls.html) that I could find is for iCal 3.0. According to that information, the question mark indicates a tentative acceptance. This makes no sense considering the single attendee accepted the event (not tentatively).

I have the setting to `Automatically retrieve CalDAV invitations from Mail` turned **on**.

I tried obvious things like closing and re-opening iCal.

Here's a screenshot of the event:

[image: Event]

And a screenshot of the same event expanded:

[image: Event expanded]

Comment: Are the people on the same network as you are (e.g. the same exchange server)? I only ask because in outlook, people outside of my exchange server always show tentative.

Comment: @Raystafarian Yep, same Exchange server (and same LAN).